# WSCDeinstallProvider returns WSAEFAULT

Tags: sockets

A seemingly simple call returns an error, but I don't understand why. Can anyone please advise?

```
GUID * Guid = (assigned elsewhere)
INT ErrorCode, rc;

rc = WSCDeinstallProvider( Guid, &ErrorCode );
// rc == SOCKET_ERROR at this point and ErrorCode == 10014 (WSAEFAULT)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by changing the order in which LSPs are uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN:

[WSCDeinstallProvider Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742231.aspx)

> WSAEFAULT The lpErrno parameter is not
>   in a valid part of the user address
>   space.

Comment: Yes, but what does that mean? I've tried allocation ErrorCode on the heap as well, but it's the same result :(